# Python 3.x: function that deals cards to x amount of players and makes a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I have this:

```
def make_deck():
    deck = []

for suit in "HDSC":
        for rank in "JQKA23456789T":
            deck.append(rank + suit)

    random.shuffle(deck)

    return deck

def cards(deck, number_players): # What should I do for this function?
    deck = make_deck()


    for i in range:
        hands = []
        player_hand = [deck.pop(), deck.pop()]

    return hands
```

I should be producing outputs that look like this:

```
hands = cards(deck, 3)
print(hands)
[['5H', '3H'], ['5S', '4S'], ['7H', '4H']]
```

So the user determines how many couple of cards are printed.

Comment: You never add anything to `hands` inside `cards()`. Define `hands` before the loop and append to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of errors as noted in the code below:

```
def make_deck():
    deck = []

    for suit in "HDSC":
        for rank in "JQKA23456789T":
            deck.append(rank + suit)

    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def cards(deck, number_players):
    hands = []  # define hands outside of the for loop
    for i in range(number_players):  # You need to specify a range
        hands.append([deck.pop(), deck.pop()])  # give each player a hand size of 2
    return hands

# finally put it all together by creating a new deck and passing it into cards()
cards(make_deck(), number_players)
```

I tried my best to intuit what the program was meant to do. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Ahh this makes sense.  My prof told me to put an empty list within the for loop and that's what confused me the most. I am, however, getting an error saying 'deck' is not defined, and I don't know why.

Comment: Don't have deck as parameter of cards. Sorry editing my response now. You can either have it as a parameter, call the function, and pass the result into the function, OR you can not have it as a parameter and call it from within the function.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark the answer as correct and close the question from further answers :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how exactly should I do the code WITH the 'deck' parameter? Sorry for these questions, I just want to understand how to use that method too.

Comment: You would call the `make_deck()` function outside the other function. I will update my code above to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, and deck argument is redundant in your defined function `cards()`. But you can rewrite the code if you want deck is changeable.

```
import random

def make_deck():

   deck = []

   for suit in "HDSC":
    for rank in "JQKA23456789T":
        deck.append(rank + suit)

   random.shuffle(deck)

   return deck

def cards(number_players): 

   deck = make_deck()
   hands = []

   for i in range(number_players):

     hands.append([deck.pop(), deck.pop()])

   return hands
```

Recall function:

```
hands = cards(3)

print(hands)
```